# Accumulator in Haskell

Tags: variables, haskell

I have this function:

```
map(\x -> if (isLetter x) then (update exp (Literal x) "") else Epsilon) "a+b+c+" where exp = Epsilon
```

and i want for each step of the map function my variable exp to not be Epsilon but to remain the same as the step before and I also want to keep the list of intermediate results. Can someone help me ?

Comment: You don't want `map`, you want a `scanl` or a `foldl`, depending on whether you want to keep the list of intermediate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to keep the intermediate results, the direct translation from what I gather to be the intent is

```
scanl (\exp x -> if (isLetter x) then update exp (Literal x) "" else Epsilon) Epsilon "a+b+c+"
```

The type of `scanl` is

```
Prelude> :t scanl
scanl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> [a]
```

the first argument is a function to combine the current "state" and the next list element, the second is the initial "state". So the above updates the "state" using the function you supplied, adjusted to take two arguments.

I'm not sure that you really want to reset the accumulator to `Epsilon` for each non-letter, if not, you'd need to change the combining function, maybe

```
\exp x -> if (isLetter x) then update exp (Literal x) "" else exp
```

to keep the old value of the accumulator for non-letters.